# Getting all manual test runs for a test suite in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

We utilise manual tests for UAT. End users are invited to run manual tests to check if the software works as expected.

I remember I could see test results for each manual test run through a series of unintuitive clicks from a test case. However, I can now only see the results of the **latest** test run and not all and **only** through the Chart tab - no change to Org/Project settings.

Am I missing something obvious? How do I see the results of all the manual test runs our end users performed for a test suite?

Thank you

Comment: Hi SGrit, any update on this, have you checked my answer? Does it answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to this page:

https://dev.azure.com///_testManagement/runs?_a=runQueryEditor

[image]

Comment: Thank you @bowman.
Is there any way to see the test runs linked to actual test case? What I mean is to find a test case and see all test runs associated with it. As an example of the workflow I'm talking about:  

1. I have a requirement in the backlog, which has a link "tested by" to a test case  
2. I'm able to navigate from that test case to all the test runs it had  

Thank you